why grpc-java uds is slower than dns?
Question:
We did a test to compare the performance between uds and dns. According to what said on the Internet, uds should be faster because it lacks many network layer protocols. However, the actual tested found that uds is at most the same as dns,in most cases The performance will be worse. Can anyone help explain ? The following are test cases and test results.
ENV:

jdk: jdk-17.0.10

grpc: 1.61.1

test machine: centos 7.9  & 64 cpu cores & 251 GB RAM

code detail
uds server core code:

 String UDS_FILE="/tmp/grpc_uds.socket";
 server = NettyServerBuilder.forAddress(new DomainSocketAddress(UDS_FILE))
                    .bossEventLoopGroup(new EpollEventLoopGroup())
                    .workerEventLoopGroup(new EpollEventLoopGroup())
                    .channelType(EpollServerDomainSocketChannel.class)
                    .maxInboundMessageSize(4*1024*1024)
                    .addService(BrSpringApplication.getBean(GreeterServiceImple.class))
                    .build().start();
  blockUtilShutDown();

uds client core code:

 String socketPath="/tmp/grpc_uds.socket";
 channel = NettyChannelBuilder.forAddress(new DomainSocketAddress(socketPath))
                    .eventLoopGroup(new EpollEventLoopGroup())
                    .channelType(EpollDomainSocketChannel.class)
                    .maxInboundMessageSize(4 * 1024 * 1024)
                    .usePlaintext().build();
GreeterGrpc.GreeterBlockingStub blockStub = GreeterGrpc.newBlockingStub(channel);
HelloRequest request = HelloRequest.newBuilder().setName(paramJson.toJSONString()).build();
        HelloReply response = getBlockStub().sayHello(request);

GreeterServiceImpl.java

@Override
    public void sayHello(HelloRequest request, StreamObserver<HelloReply> responseObserver) {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        logger.warn("request:{}", request.getName());
        try {
            if (Context.current().isCancelled()) {
                logger.warn("deadline cancalled,deadline:{}", Context.current().getDeadline());
                responseObserver.onError(new Exception("Cancelled by client"));
                return;
            }
            JSONObject msgRequest= JSONObject.parseObject(request.getName());
            int num=msgRequest.getIntValue("factor");
            String msg=msgRequest.getString("message");
            StringBuilder messageBack = new StringBuilder("rep-");
            for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
                messageBack.append(msg).append("|");
            }
//            logger.warn("response:{}", messageBack);
            HelloReply response = HelloReply.newBuilder().setMessage(messageBack + ",ms:" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime)).build();
            responseObserver.onNext(response);
            responseObserver.onCompleted();

        } catch (BrException e) {
            logger.error("BrException,code:{},message:{}", e.getCode(), e.getMessage());
            HelloReply response = HelloReply.newBuilder().setMessage(e.getMessage()).build();
            responseObserver.onNext(response);
            responseObserver.onCompleted();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error("sys error", ex);
            HelloReply response=HelloReply.newBuilder().setMessage(ex.getMessage()).build();
            responseObserver.onNext(response);
            responseObserver.onCompleted();
        }
    }

dns sever core code:

String port="80";
server = NettyServerBuilder.forPort(port)
                    .maxInboundMessageSize(4*1024*1024)
                    .addService(BrSpringApplication.getBean(GreeterServiceImple.class))
                    .build().start();
blockUtilShutDown();

dns client core code:
String ip="localhost:80"
channel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forTarget(ip).usePlaintext().build();
GreeterGrpc.GreeterBlockingStub blockStub = GreeterGrpc.newBlockingStub(channel);
HelloRequest request = HelloRequest.newBuilder().setName(paramJson.toJSONString()).build();
        HelloReply response=getBlockStub().sayHello(request);

test result:




client message size
response message size
thead
totalnum
type
num
total cost(ms)
qps




12B
60B
50
5000000
dns
1
127359ms
5535.790199357721


12B
60B
50
5000000
dns
2
126051ms
5593.233722858208


12B
60B
50
5000000
dns
3
128828ms
5472.666687366101


12B
60B
50
5000000
uds
1
133212ms
5292.561510974987


12B
60B
50
5000000
uds
2
128315ms
5494.546265050852


12B
60B
50
5000000
uds
3
127177ms
5543.712337922738


12B
120B
50
5000000
dns
1
125919ms
5599.097070338868


12B
120B
50
5000000
dns
2
122034ms
5777.346509989019


12B
120B
50
5000000
dns
3
120439ms
5853.857172510566


12B
120B
50
5000000
uds
1
123538ms
5707.010830675582


12B
120B
50
5000000
uds
2
126988ms
5551.963209122122


12B
120B
50
5000000
uds
3
126450ms
5575.584847765916


12B
6kb
50
5000000
dns
1
123176ms
5723.783074624926


12B
6kb
50
5000000
dns
2
127242ms
5540.880401125414


12B
6kb
50
5000000
dns
3
121556ms
5800.06502352825


12B
6kb
50
5000000
uds
1
131939ms
5343.626251525327


12B
6kb
50
5000000
uds
2
133399ms
5285.1423473939085


12B
6kb
50
5000000
uds
3
130091ms
5419.534817935138


5kb
5kb
50
5000000
dns
1
133404ms
5284.9442595424425


5kb
5kb
50
5000000
dns
2
130532ms
5401.225017620201


5kb
5kb
50
5000000
dns
3
130145ms
5417.286134695916


5kb
5kb
50
5000000
uds
1
140809ms
5007.0144948121215


5kb
5kb
50
5000000
uds
2
140685ms
5011.427685965099


5kb
5kb
50
5000000
uds
3
140992ms
5000.515660463005



I expected grpc uds to be faster than dns , but it's not. all test cases are on the localhost machine , and i put the uds path to the ssd disk , but fount it's performance as  same as hdd. I alse changed server and client memory from 2GB to 6 GB ,but it doesn't any improvement
